# Navigation on click of DetailDisclosureButton?

Tags: iphone

I am using disclosure btn in UITableViewcell.When i use :

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

it navigates to anotherViewController where as when i use following it does not navigate on btn click

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

What should I do for navigation on click of DetailDisclosureButton?

Answer (score 11):

handle event here -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: +1. To get the cell from the indexPath you may want to store your underlying data structure as an array with the rows of the table corresponding to the index of the array (e.g if it's a list of items then the `MyListItem` class or similar). Then you either link the `UITableViewCell` to your `MyListItem` via an instance variable/property, or store in your `MyListItem` a flag indicating whether you should navigate when selecting it. If you can read the cell, check `if([(MyListItem *)[myItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cell].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)`.